# How to publish custom object to DLQ queue using camel OnException

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have something like below:

```
    onException(Exception.class)
        .maximumRedeliveries(2).redeliveryDelay(1000L).asyncDelayedRedelivery() 
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, LOGGER, "Body before process ->> \"${body}\" for the cause of ->  \"${exception.message}\"")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("body", exchange.getIn().getBody());
                obj.put("errMsg", "testErrorMsg");
                exchange.getIn().setBody(obj);
            }
        })
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, LOGGER, "Body after process ->> \"${body}\" for the cause of ->  \"${exception.message}\"")
        .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly).setFaultBody(constant(true))
        .setHeader(RabbitMQConstants.REQUEUE, constant(Boolean.FALSE)).handled(false);
```

Original message:

```
{"key" : "123" }
```

and I am expecting custom message as below while sending to DLQ:

```
{
  "body": {
    "key": "123"
  },
  "errMsg": "testErrorMsg"
}
```

In logs, I can see body is converted as per my expectation but in DLQ queue it showing the original message.

It is possible to modify message before sending to DLQ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!
You may use [Deal Letter Channel EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/dead-letter-channel.html), with its [`onPrepareFailure`](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/dead-letter-channel.html#deadLetterChannel-OnPrepareFailure) to add a custom `Processor`, to modify the `Exchange` before delivering it to the DLQ.